# Merging equal sized heaps

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

Can someone explain why the following algorithm for merging heaps isn't correct?

Lets say we have two (max) heaps H1 and H2.

To merge them:

create an artificial dummy node whose key value is negative infinity and place it at the root with H1 and H2 attached as children. Then do an O(log n) bubble down step that swaps the root eventually to a leaf position, where it is ultimately deleted. The resulting structure is a merged heap.

I have seen claims both on wikipedia and elsewhere that merging two equal sized heaps is a Theta(n) operation, in contradiction with what I've written above.

Answer (score 3):

At least as heaps are normally implemented (with the links implicit in the placement of the nodes), a part you seem to be almost ignoring ("with H1 and H2 attached as children") has linear complexity by itself.

As a heap is normally implemented, you have a linear collection (e.g., an array) where each element N has elements 2N and 2N+1 as its children (e.g., with a 1-based array, the children of element 1 are elements 2 and 3, and the children of element 2 are 4 and 5). Therefore, you need to interleave the elements from the two heaps before we get to the starting point for your merge operation.

If you started with explicitly linked binary trees (just following heap-style rules instead of, for example, binary-search tree ordering) then you'd be right, the merge can be done with logarithmic complexity -- but I doubt that original article intends to refer to that kind of structure.

Comment: I'd like to see the keyword "array" in this answer. This problem is explicitly an array-as-heap problem, as the wikipedia also states.

Comment: @thiton: Yeah, I was in the middle of adding that as you commented.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. But then I wonder why anyone would want to implement a heap as an array when implementing it as a linked list aka binary tree would provide easy merges?

Comment: @user2097517: First, it saves memory (you'd need four pointers per node to traverse to parent, both children and sibling). Second, on a modern CPU it's faster (getting to another node requires only a tiny bit of math instead of a fetch from memory). Finally, most uses of heaps don't require merging anyway.

Comment: IIRC, implicit heaps have their performance edge because of the smaller node size:  the sheer reduction in data movement and cache occupancy is important!  However, to be fair:  explicit heaps and semi-heaps typically only have two pointers per node; and if merging is important to your application, you should probably consider them in preference to implicit heaps.

Comment: If merging is **really, really** important, you should consider [Fibonacci Heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) that can merge in O(1).

Answer (score 2):

If you are implementing it as a tree your solution is correct. But as Jerry mentioned, merging array based heaps cannot be done in sub-linear time.

Depending on the frequency and size of the merge I suggest you use a virtual heap. You can implement it as heap of heaps (with arrays). After a few merges you can lazily merge multiple internal heaps into one large heap.